# Expected value of Taylor series with central moments of binomial variate

Tags: pr.probability, taylor-series, binomial-distribution

I want to understand [this entry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145678/expected-value-of-logarithm-of-a-binomial-random-variable), but do not understand how the $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ in the accepted answer comes into play.

I reproduce the question here: We have $x \sim \mathrm{Bin}_{p,n}$ and want to approximate $E[\ln(x+1)]$ with a Taylor series. And I'm only interested in the case when the Taylor series is convergent for all values of $x$. (This condition implies $p> \frac{1}{2} $). Thus,
\begin{equation}
E[T_{x_0=np}\left(\ln(x+1)\right)]=\ln(np + 1) - \sum_{i=1}\frac{(-1)^{i}}{i(np-1)^{i}}E[(x-np)^{i}]
\end{equation}
In the accepted solution, the suggestion is to use the following approximation:
\begin{equation}
E[\ln(x+1)]=\ln(np + 1) - \frac{np(1-p)}{2(np+1)^{2}} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\end{equation}
Where the second summand comes from the variance term $(i = 2)$. I have not found an upper bound for central moments of Binomial variates that could lead to the big Oh notation. Plugging in a closed form expression for the respective central moments from [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andreas-Knoblauch/publication/220222321_Closed-form_Expressions_for_the_Moments_of_the_Binomial_Probability_Distribution/links/5552fca708ae6943a86d8fb1/Closed-form-Expressions-for-the-Moments-of-the-Binomial-Probability-Distribution.pdf) does not lead me to this approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to bound the Binomial central moments. A good (very general) estimate is provided by the Marcinkiweicz-Zygmund inequality, in the sharp form due to Burkholder [1],  Writing $X-np$ as a sum of $n$ i.i.d. mean zero variables $Y_i$ taking values
$1-p$ and $-p$, observe that the square function S(X) defined on page 87 in [1] is bounded by $n^{1/2}$. Theorem 3.1 page 87 in [1] then gives
$$E[|X-np|^k] \le \bigl((k-1)n^{1/2}\bigr)^k \,.$$
The case $k=3$ is best dealt with directly, and here we cannot afford the absolute value inside the expectation:
$$E[(X-np)^3] =\sum_{i,j,\ell \le n} E[Y_iY_jY_\ell]=\sum_{i \le n} E[Y_i^3] \le n \,.$$

[1] Burkholder, Donald L. "Sharp inequalities for martingales and stochastic integrals." Astérisque 157, no. 158 (1988): 75-94.
http://www.numdam.org/article/AST_1988__157-158__75_0.pdf

Remark: In my answer I focus on the question regarding Binomial central moments. for estimating the logarithm, see Iosif Pinelis' answer.

Answer (score 2):

"And I'm only interested in the case when the Taylor series is convergent for all values of $x$." -- There is no such Taylor series for $\ln$ (which is only defined on $(0,\infty)$).

However, to get the desired $O(1/n^2)$, you do not need a convergent series; you do not need any series at all. Instead, you need the Taylor expansion
\begin{equation}
    \ln(1+u)=u-u^2/2+u^3/3+O(u^4) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
for $u\ge-1/2$ (say), with a universal constant in $O(u^4)$.

Indeed, letting
\begin{equation}
    U:=\frac{X-np}{np+a}, \tag{2}
\end{equation}
for all real $a>0$ you can write
\begin{align*}
    &E\ln(X+a)-\ln(np+a) \\
    &=E\ln(1+U) \\ 
    &=E\ln(1+U)1(U\ge-1/2) \\ 
    &+E\ln(1+U)1(U<-1/2).  \tag{3}
\end{align*}
By (1),
\begin{align*}
    &E\ln(1+U)\,1(U\ge-1/2) \\ 
    &=E(U-U^2/2+U^3/3+O(U^4))\,1(U\ge-1/2) \\ 
    &=E(U-U^2/2+U^3/3)+O(EU^4) \\ 
    &-E(U-U^2/2+U^3/3)1(U<-1/2). \tag{4}
\end{align*}
Now we are going to use (say) Rosenthal's inequality (see e.g. formula (7) in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-43/issue-5/Exact-Rosenthal-type-bounds/10.1214/14-AOP942.full)), which implies
\begin{equation}
    EU^4=O(1/n^2) \tag{5}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    EU^6=O(1/n^3); \tag{6}
\end{equation}
here in what follows, the constants in $O(\cdot)$ may depend only on $p$ (and, in (11) and (12), also on $a$).
By (6), for $m=0,1,2,3$ we have $|U|^m\,1(U<-1/2)|\le U^6(1/2)^{m-6}$ and hence
\begin{equation}
    |EU^m\,1(U<-1/2)|\le EU^6(1/2)^{m-6}=O(1/n^3). \tag{7}
\end{equation}
Also,
\begin{equation}
    EU=0,\quad EU^2=\frac{npq}{(np+a)^2} \tag{8}
\end{equation}
(where $q:=1-p$),
$E(X-np)^3=n(pq^3-qp^3)=O(n)$ and hence
\begin{equation}
    EU^3=O(1/n^2). \tag{9}
\end{equation}
By (4), (5), (7), (8), (9),
\begin{align*}
    &E\ln(1+U)\,1(U\ge-1/2) \\ 
    &=E(U-U^2/2+U^3/3)+O(1/n^2) \\ 
    &=-\frac{npq}{2(np+a)^2}+O(1/n^2). \tag{10}
\end{align*}
By (2) and the obvious inequality $X\ge0$, we have $1+U\ge\frac a{np+a}$. Also, if $U<-1/2$, then $1+U<1/2$, whence $\ln(1+U)<0$ and hence $|\ln(1+U)|\le \ln\frac{np+a}a$.
So,
\begin{align*}
    &E|\ln(1+U)\,1(U<-1/2)| \\ 
    &\le\ln\frac{np+a}a E1(U<-1/2)=O(1/n^2), \tag{11}
\end{align*}
by (7) with $m=0$.
Now (3) and (10) yield
\begin{align*}
    &E\ln(X+a)=\ln(np+a)-\frac{npq}{2(np+a)^2}+O(1/n^2), \tag{12}
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: thank you for this amazing proof. I have two questions. 1, The Taylor expansion in eq. 1 is valid for $|u|<1$. Now $U \in (-1, \frac{n}{\alpha})$. How is it garanteed, that eq. 1 is applicable for all $U1(U\geq -\frac12)$? 2, I understand eq. 11, that it is assumed that $E|\ln(1+U)1(U<-\frac12)|\leq E|U|^m1(U<-\frac12)$ for $m \in \{0,1,2,3\}$, which is not true. Could you help me to understand it better?

Comment: @qwert : Concerning (1): Use the Taylor expansion for $|u|\le1/2$ and then use the boundedness of $(\ln(1+u)-(u-u^2/2+u^3/3))/u^4$ for $u\ge1/2$. Concerning (11): I have added details on that. (I did not use there what you thought I used).